# Getting epoch time from calendar view in android

Tags: java, android

i need to get the epoch time in milliseconds of the date selected by the user from my calendar view. I use the metod `calendarView.getDate()` and I pass the result in my retrofit request. When I get the date back and set it as date in the view using `calendarView.setDate(milliseconds)` the calendar goes to dates like the '70s and if i take the number and convert it into date format using a simple python program or an online converter it gives me like if it is 2030.

I tried to set the minDate of the calendar view to 01/01/1970 but it didn't changed. I won't share my code because i just used the two methods i said.

Thank you for helping me

Comment: `"When I get the date back [...]"` - what you mean by that? what date? the same you got from `calendarView`?

Comment: I mean when I get from the external db using retrofit requests the number that I saved before

Comment: so they are equal and yet one shows 2019 and the other 2030?

Comment: Sorry, I explained bad. There are two different activities. In the first i take the number from a calendar view when the user selects the date. In the second one i take the number and i set it as date in another calendar view but the number is the same